# Using VB Net to communicate with an HID

Tags: vb.net-2010, hid

I have an Omron M10-IT blood pressure monitor (which is an USB HID). Currently I upload the results to the Omron site, then download the data as a csv file, and, finally read the data into an access file. Unfortunately Omron are shortly to cease support. It seems mad to manually transcribe the results when the device supports a data exchange protocol.

For a couple of weeks I have searching the internet in an attempt to interface with the device with a view to downloading the raw data to my PC. With absolutely no luck! I am using VB Net Framework 4.8 on Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 11 PC.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated, especially if sample code was also available. For instance is the HidDeviceObject available in VB or is it only exposed in a version of C? It seems to be defines in "hidsdi.h" for C, so what assembly reference and import do I require for VB? Links to any tutorial material or articles would be most welcome.

Have found a couple of article "How to Communicate with its USB Devices using HID Protocol" which is for C# and "USB HID Template for Visual Basic" which dates back to 2010 and is targeted at x32 cpus.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest you look at HidApi.Net